# R : count similar numbers in two vectors

Tags: r, function

```
  shared_numbers<- function(x, y){
  shared_numbers=0
  for(r in 1:5) {
    for(c in 1:5) {
      if (x[c]==result[r]){shared_numbers = shared_numbers+1}  
    }
  }
  return(shared_numbers)
}

#Example
shared_numbers(c(12, 17, 37, 58, 81, 89),  c(4, 19, 37, 81, 87, 19))
[1] 2
```

The problem is this function is very slow when I need to use it a lot.
I think it because of the loops, but I don't know how to avoid them.

**Question :** How to optimize this function ?
*Thanks Richard, sum(result %in% combination) works very well.*

**Question 2 :** How to apply this shared_number function to thousands of combination without using a for loop ?

Comment: Could you show us how it's being used?  With an example run

Comment: I added an concrete example !

Comment: It looks like `sum(result %in% combination)` might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get away from the looping by using `%in%`

```
result <- c(12, 17, 37, 58, 81, 89)
combo <- c(4, 19, 37, 81, 87, 19)
sum(result %in% combo)
# [1] 2
```

You could replicate this, say twelve times, with

```
set.seed(25)
repCombo <- replicate(12, sample(90, 6), simplify = FALSE)
vapply(repCombo, function(x) sum(result %in% x), 1L)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1
```

With regard to your comment about different data structures, this would work

```
lottoSum <- function(result, combo) 
{
    f <- function(x, y) sum(x %in% y)
    if (is.matrix(combo)) {
        apply(combo, 2, f, x = result)
    } else if (is.vector(combo) && is.atomic(combo)) {
        f(result, combo)
    } else {
        vapply(combo, f, x = result, 1L, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    }
}

lottoSum(result, as.data.frame(repCombo))      ## data frame
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1
lottoSum(result, repCombo)                     ## list
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1
lottoSum(result, combo)                        ## vector
# [1] 2
lottoSum(result, matrix(unlist(repCombo), 6))  ## matrix
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1
```

Comment: It's a simulation, so I figured I'd show you how to replicate it :-)

Comment: How could I used vapply with a data frame or a matrix instead of a list of vector like in your example ?

Comment: `vapply` will run across the columns of a data frame just like `lapply` and `sapply`.  For a matrix, I'll look into finding the best way and come back in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is complete !

I've just have 1 more question.

It works well if the structure of "combo is in column (1 combination per column).

How to do the same if the structure is in row (1 combination per row) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65008/discussion-between-ophelie-and-richard-scriven).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the 'intersect' function:

```
> length(intersect(c(12, 17, 37, 58, 81, 89)
+         ,  c(4, 19, 37, 81, 87, 19)
+         )
+     )
[1] 2
>
```